# Are random variables having a uniform joint PDF always uncorrelated?

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with joint PDF $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=1$ in the triangular region bordered by $y=1+x$, $y=1-x$, and $y=0$. In this case, the covariance $\sigma_{X,Y}=0,$ as can be checked by directly calculating $E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$. Is it the case that for any random variables having a uniform joint PDF over any arbitrary region they will always be uncorrelated?

Comment: No; imagine a parallelogram that approximates a segment of the 45 degree line. $Y$ will almost be a perfect predictor of $X$ in that case.

Comment: So if the PDF has even symmetry then yes, the correlation is 0, right?

Answer (score 0):

No, imagine $(X,Y)$ uniform on the triangle $0\lt y\lt x\lt1$, then $\mathbb E(Y\mid X)=\frac12X$ hence $\mathbb E(XY)=\frac12\mathbb E(X^2)$ and $\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)=\frac12\mathrm{var}(X)\ne0$.

On the other hand, if the symmetries of the distribution of $(X,Y)$ ensure that $\mathbb E(Y\mid X)=c$ for some constant $c$ (which is the case in your example, for $c=1$), then $\mathbb E(XY)=c\mathbb E(X)$ and $\mathbb E(Y)=c$ hence $\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)=0$.